# Selenium Firefox illegal key value `unexpectedAlertBehaviour`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am trying to run Selenium standalone firefox inside a Docker container, with RSpec 5.1, Rails 5.2.1 and Capybara 2.11.0

When I run the tests I get the following error:

```bash
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [unexpectedAlertBehaviour]
```

My code looks like the following:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :headless_firefox do |app|
  capa = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
  capa['unexpectedAlertBehaviour']= 'accept'
  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    url: "http://firefox-server:4444",
    capabilities: capa
  )

  driver
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_firefox
```

I have also tried with `'ignore'` instead of `'accept'` aswell as omitting the capabilities entirely.

When running the Chrome standalone, which looks like this:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,800')

  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    url: "http://chrome-server:4444",
    options: options
  )

  driver
end
```

I don't get the error.

Do anyone know how to fix this?

This is the docker image I am using

```yaml
firefox-server:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox
    ports:
      - "7900:7900"
      - "4444:4444"
```

EDIT:

Added version details

Comment: Include capybara tag when you raise capybara related questions.

Comment: @Rajagopalan oh yeah, of course. I've added version details now

Comment: I was asking about the tag. I have added it.

Comment: The versions of everything you’re using are REALLY old. Also you didn’t include the version of the one package that matters in this case, what version of selenium-webdriver are you using?